# Tokenizing full csv resulting in only last line?

Tags: python, csv, nltk, tokenize

I want to tokenize my full CSV. The below code will open all the CSV and print it. When I try to tokenize it, it only tokenize last line of the CSV rather then full CSV.
Can anyone help me to tokenize full CSV?

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

with open ('OCD_lookup.csv') as file_object:
    for OCDline in file_object:
        print(OCDline)
tokens = word_tokenize(EAline)
print(tokens)
```

Comment: What is `EAline`? It's not defined. Don't you want to put `word_tokenize` inside the for loop, if it needs to be run for each line?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tokenize all the text in your csv file, you will have to go through the lines and the fields in those lines

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

complete_list=[]
with open ('OCD_lookup.csv') as file_object:
    for OCDline in file_object:
        complete_list+=word_tokenize(OCDline)
```

Comment: import difflib 
from difflib import get_close_matches

search_text='collision' 

matches=get_close_matches(search_text,tokens_OCDlookup, n=10, cutoff=1)   
print(matches)

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: Thanks for the above help.I have got the right output from your above help but when I try to find a string search_text='collision' or any other. It will only find it in the last line tokenize list of the CSV. I am using difflib. Sorry for wrong format above.I am using StackOverflow for the first time

Comment: No problem if you got the right answer you can edit my response above!

Comment: The above code is tokenizing all the CSV in small separate lists. Can you please tell me how can I make one list so then I can find matches using difflib?

Comment: @AbdulWahab updated! Complete list is the list which contains everything!